# Dimension of kernel of a linear map $\phi: M_n(\mathbb R) \to \mathbb R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb R)$ be a fixed matrix. Let us define a linear map $\phi: M_n(\mathbb R) \to \mathbb R^n$ by
\begin{align*}
X \mapsto (XA-AX)e_1,
\end{align*}
where $e_1$ is the standard basis vector. Is it possible for us to determine the dimension of $\text{ker}(\phi)$? Intuitively, the whole space is $n^2$ and we have one linear equation, it seems like $\ker(\phi)$ should be of dimension $n^2-1$. Is this correct?

Comment: What if we have $A=I$?

Comment: What if we exclude the case $A= \pm I$? Would the answer still be heavily dependent on $A$?

Comment: And $2I$, and $3I$, and all other multiples of $I$. Apart from that, the actual crux of this problem is to tell whether the result depends on $A$. It's what you're _actually_ asked about: If $A$ is not a multiple of $I$, can you find an $X$ which makes the first column of $AX-XA$ non-zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\phi(X)$ is a vector with $n$ components. So, you have $n$ linear equations, not one.

The matrix representation of $\phi$ with respect to the standard basis of $M_n(\mathbb R)$ is
$$
(Ae_1)^T\otimes I-e_1^T\otimes A=\pmatrix{a_{11}I-A&a_{21}I&\cdots&a_{n1}I}.
$$
Therefore
$$
\operatorname{nullity}(\phi)=
\begin{cases}
n^2-n&\text{if } a_{i1}\ne0\text{ for some }i>1,\\
n^2-\operatorname{rank}(a_{11}I-A)&\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
It can be any number between $n^2-n$ and $n^2$. For instances:

- when $A=E_{12}=e_1e_2^T$, $\phi(X)=(x_{21},\ x_{22}-x_{11},\ x_{31},\ldots,x_{n1})^T$ and $\operatorname{nullity}(\phi)=n^2-n$;
- when $A$ is a diagonal matrix whose first diagonal entry is zero, $\phi(X)=-AX\mathbf e_1$ and $\operatorname{nullity}(\phi)=n^2-\text{number of nonzero diagonal entries of }A$.